# Every time I print with my Ender 3 V2, I get a bubbly ring around the bottom. How can I fix this?

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla

I have a Creality Ender 3 V2. I have done quite a few prints with it using only PLA. When the prints are done, there is always a bubbly looking ring around the bottom of them. I have tried using rafts, and changing slicer settings to fix this and nothing has worked. Are there any ways I can try to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @lil mikey. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem. Also, if you could add a picture of what is happening that would help out a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your bed height, Z axis mechanics, or "automatic bed leveling" if you're using that. During this section of the print, the nozzle is not accurately at the requested distance from the bed, and material is spewing out to the sides where the printer tries to print the next layer too close to the previous one.

Try using the printer controls to manually move the head in small increments around 0.1 or 0.2 mm, and measure that the distance between the bed surface and gantry changes by the expected amount each time you move. I expect you'll find that it doesn't.

We'll probably need further information to track down exactly why it's not happening.